# Regex in java to find pattern like % from given string

Tags: java, regex

I am a noob to regex.

I have string like:-

```
1.9% 2581/candaemon: 0.4% user + 1.4% kernel
```

and i have to extract all patterns matched with this type **%**

Like:- for given str result should be

```
matcher.group(0) total 1.9  
matcher.group(0) user 0.4  
matcher.group(0) kernel 1.5
```

So far i have tried with this code but no luck :-

```
while ((_temp = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {   
                    if(_temp.contains("candaemon"))
                    {   
                        double total = 0, user = 0, kernel = 0, iowait = 0;

                        //Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\%\\d+)?)");
                        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\%\\d)\\%");
                        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(_temp);

                        int i = 0;
                        while(matcher.find())
                        {   
                            System.out.println("MonitorThreadCPULoad _temp "+_temp+" and I is "+i);
                            if(i == 0)
                            {   
                                total = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(0));
                                System.out.println("matcher.group(0) total "+total);
                            }
                            if(i == 1)
                            {   
                                user = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(0));
                                System.out.println("matcher.group(0) user "+user);
                            }
                            if(i == 2)
                            {
                                kernel = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(0));
                                System.out.println("matcher.group(0) kernel "+kernel);
                            }       
                            i++;
                        }

                        System.out.println("total "+total+" user"+user+" kernel"+kernel+" count"+count);
                        System.out.println("cpuDataDump[count] "+cpuDataDump[count]);
                        cpuDataDump[count] = total+"";
                        cpuDataDump[(count+1)] = user+"";
                        cpuDataDump[(count+2)] = kernel+"";
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about this by first splitting your input string on `%`, and then using a regular expression on each fragment to extract the number you want:

```
String input = "1.9% 2581/candaemon: 0.4% user + 1.4% kernel";
String[] theParts = input.split("\\%");
for (int i=0; i < theParts.length; ++i) {
    theParts[i] = theParts[i].replaceAll("(.*)\\s([0-9\\.]*)", "$2");
}

System.out.println("total "  + theParts[0]);
System.out.println("user "   + theParts[1]);
System.out.println("kernel " + theParts[2]);
```

**Output:**

```
total 1.9
user 0.4
kernel 1.4
```

Here is a link where you can test the regular expression which is being used on each part of the input string:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cW9aN5/1)

Comment: Superb, neat and clean. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can test  (..[0-9])\% this pattern. try your string to find appropriate pattern on Regex side ->[regex](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: yes this seems to be perfect one as i check on given link by you. But i am not able to frame it as a pattern Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(..[0-9])\%"); Its giving me error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: try to put it in regex  side create appropriate pattern. i am sure that it will work...... thanks.